# Присвоить переменной вывод команды printf

Tags: bash, консоль, shell

Есть текстовый файл ***list.txt***, в котором каждая строка (а их более 200) содержит информацию по дате типа: ***"04/08/1995 - какой-то текст ..."***. Год может быть разный, а день и месяц - повторяться, т.е. несколько строк с одной датой ***04/08/***.
Нужно прочитать файл построчно с выбором строк с одинаковой датой ***день/месяц*** (год не важен) относительно сегодня: **date +'%d/%m'**.
Решение нашёл такое:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if [[ "$line" != "" ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "$line" | grep "^$(date +'%d/%m')"
  fi
done < list.txt
```

Но в данном решении вывод идёт в терминал командой **printf**, а нужно получать выбранные строки в переменную.

Пробовал **printf** присвоить переменной:

```
result=$(printf '%s\n' "$line" | grep "^$(date +'%d/%m')")
```

на выходе не совсем тот результат (проверял выводом переменной в терминал с помощью **echo** и **printf**

Ожидаемый результат (пример):

```
04/08/1888 - какой-то текст
04/08/1999 - ещё текст
```

С **printf "$result"** вывод:

```
1999 - тексттекст
```

С **printf -v $result** вывод:

```
04/08/188804/08/1999printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
```

строки с ***printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]*** по количеству строк в файле ***list.txt***

С **echo "$result"** вывод:

```
04/08/1888 - какой-то текст
04/08/1999 - ещё текст
```

но выводятся пустые строки согласно количества строк в файле ***list.txt***.

Comment: Приложите, что вы ожидали получить, а что получили фактически

Comment: Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: вывод в переменную без '$': `printf -v result ...`

Comment: Без '$' выводит только `printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]` по количеству строк в файле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос до конца не понятен, но все же постараюсь ответить:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
#_____^^^^^___для чего используется сброс разделителя полей
  if [[ "$line" != "" ]]; then
#_______________^^^______лучше использовать стандартные ключи if
#[[ -z $line ]] && переменная пустая
#[[ -n $line ]] && переменная не пустая
    printf '%s\n' "$line" | grep "^$(date +'%d/%m')"
#___^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^___ данную часть можно обойти
# например использовав стандартную возможность шелл работу с перменными
#grep "^$(date +'%d/%m')" <<< "$line"
#Но в данном случае у вас нет проверки выбралась ли строка или нет
  fi
done < list.txt
```

Конструкция как и printf на мой взгляд избыточны, оставил комментарии в коде выше

```
#Вариант 1 - создавать массив неопределенной длинны
while read -r line; do
    array+=( "$line" )
    #посмотреть длину массива ${#array[@]}
    #развернуть весь массив ${array[@]}
    #получить первое значение ${array[0]}
done< <(grep "^$(date +'%d/%m')" list.txt)

#Вариант 2, просто записать вывод команды в переменную
var=`grep "^$(date +'%d/%m')" list.txt`
```

По поводу команды:

```
result=$(printf '%s\n' "$line" | grep "^$(date +'%d/%m')")
#_____^___каждую итерацию цикла переменная будет перезаписываться и будет
#содержать только последние значение, для записи значения в конец переменной 
#лучше использовать +=
```

В данном случае в команде уже предусмотрен переход на новую строку '%s\n', но `grep` не выбирает новую строку, что бы переменная имела вид данные\nданные\n, попробуйте уже как стринг добавить перевод строки:

```
result+=`printf '%s\n' "$line" | grep "^$(date +'%d/%m')"`\\n
result+=`printf '%s\\n' "$line" | grep "^$(date +'%d/%m')"`
___________________^_____экранирование
#printf $result
#echo -e $result
```

---

Если я не правильно понял проблему, то готов ответить на вопросы и отредактировать данное сообщение.

Answer (score 1):

можно просто сделать проще:

```
result=$(awk -v d=$(date +'%d/%m') -F'/' '$1"/"$2 == d' list.txt)
```

простой пример:

```
$ cat list.txt
05/08/1888 - какой-то текст 1
05/08/1999 - какой-то текст 2
03/08/1999 - какой-то текст 3
05/02/1299 - какой-то текст 4
$ date +'%d/%m'
05/08
$ result=$(awk -v d=$(date +'%d/%m') -F'/' '$1"/"$2 == d' list.txt)
echo "$result"
05/08/1888 - какой-то текст 1
05/08/1999 - какой-то текст 2
```

Comment: Упростить можно и так: `result=$(grep "^$(date +'%d/%m')" list.txt)`

Comment: @just3man, можно и так, главное чтобы это решало вашу проблему